# Как соединить все точки графа и записать в отдельный массив

Tags: python, алгоритм, graph

```
l = [1,4,3,2]
R = [(1,2,1), (1,3,4),(1,4,2),(1,5,4),(2,3,4),(2,4,3),(2,5,4),(3,4,1),(3,5,3),(4,5,2)]
```

У меня есть вот это и мне нужно получить [(1,4,2),(3,4,1),(2,3,4),(1,2,1)]

Я не пойму как записать что бы оно начинало каждый раз с начала, а не только брало первый и всё

Comment: Что это все означает и как получен результат?

Comment: Это список графов, результат получен из списка R, 1 - 4 это тоже что и 4 - 1 и в списке R это 3 элемент (1,4,2). из l это 0 и 1 индекс. Следующий будет 1 и 2 элемент 4 и 3, это тоже что 3 и 4, в l это 7 элемент

Comment: Ничего не ясно. Если вы тщательно сформулируете вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен другим, то не исключено, что в этом процессе сами разберётесь, что нужно делать.

Answer (score 0):

Пару элементов из `l` ищем среди префиксов элементов из `R`:

```
l = [1,4,3,2]
R = [(1,2,1), (1,3,4),(1,4,2),(1,5,4),(2,3,4),(2,4,3),(2,5,4),(3,4,1),(3,5,3),(4,5,2)]

d = {frozenset(r[:2]): r for r in R} 
g = [d[frozenset(p)] for p in zip(l, l[1:] + l[:1])]
print(g)
```

> ```
> [(1, 4, 2), (3, 4, 1), (2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 1)]
> ```

**P.S.** Задача поставлена замечательно неясно.

Comment: Ваш хрустальный шар, видимо, хорош! ;)

Comment: @MBo, вот и посмотрим. Задача меня заинтересовали именно своей неясностью. Даны вход и выход, предъявите оптимальную (в каком-то смысле) функцию. :)

Comment: У меня получилось более банальное решение, я сначала просто в пустой массив добавил граф первого и последнего числа, а потом каждое сочетание цифр(нужных мне графов) по очереди искал в R. есть числа 1-4, прохожусь по R и получаю (1,4,2) и добавляю его в тот массив который был создан что бы получить результат и так столько итераций сколько у меня длина l-1

Answer (score 0):

```
def graph(R,l):
r = []
k = 0

for q in R:
    if(l[0] == q[0] and l[-1] == q[1]):
        r.append(q)
    elif(l[0] == q[1] and l[-1] == q[0]):
        r.append(q)

for k in range(0,len(l)-1):
    for x in R:
        if(l[k] == x[0] and l[k+1] == x[1]):
            r.append(x)
        elif(l[k] == x[1] and l[k+1] == x[0]):
            r.append(x)
return r
```